# Extracting the last string from each array element

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've created an array as follows:

```
declare -p RePos=("$MntPnt"/Module-Basesystem\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-basesystem-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Server-Applications\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-application-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Development-Tools\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-development_tools-x86_64
                 )
```

I'm then attempting (but failing to) print/echo last string from each array element i.e.

```
sles-15-sp3-server-basesystem-x86_64
sles-15-sp3-server-application-x86_64
sles-15-sp3-server-development_tools
```

Using the following:

```
for Add_RePos in "${!RePos[@]}"
do
  echo "
  $(tput setaf 2)--> Creating "${RePos[@]-1}" Repositories <--$(tput sgr0)
  "
done
```

However, when I run the associated script, I'm not getting the desired result and just end up with all elements of the array.

```
# sh CreateReposWithISO.sh

declare -a RePos=([0]="/mnt/Module-Basesystem sles-15-sp3-server-basesystem-x86_64" [1]="/mnt/Module-Server-Applications sles-15-sp3-server-application-x86_64" [2]="/mnt/Module-Development-Tools sles-15-sp3-server-development_tools-x86_64")

  --> Creating /mnt/Module-Basesystem sles-15-sp3-server-basesystem-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Server-Applications sles-15-sp3-server-application-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Development-Tools sles-15-sp3-server-development_tools-x86_64 Repositories <--


  --> Creating /mnt/Module-Basesystem sles-15-sp3-server-basesystem-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Server-Applications sles-15-sp3-server-application-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Development-Tools sles-15-sp3-server-development_tools-x86_64 Repositories <--


  --> Creating /mnt/Module-Basesystem sles-15-sp3-server-basesystem-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Server-Applications sles-15-sp3-server-application-x86_64 /mnt/Module-Development-Tools sles-15-sp3-server-development_tools-x86_64 Repositories <--
```

```
# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

I attempted several different formats to produce my desired result but to no avail i.e.

```
${RePos[${#RePos[@]} - 1]}
```

Comment: `for i in "${RePos[@]#* }"; do echo "$i"; done`?

Comment: What is the definition of "last string"? Do you mean _everything after the first space_, or _everything after the last space_, or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looping on the array indices instead of values, and then trying to operate on the array instead of the value. Just loop on each value and operate on that instead:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a RePos=("$MntPnt"/Module-Basesystem\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-basesystem-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Server-Applications\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-application-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Development-Tools\ sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-development_tools-x86_64
                 )

for Add_RePos in "${RePos[@]}"
do
  echo "
  $(tput setaf 2)--> Creating ${Add_RePos#* } Repositories <--$(tput sgr0)
  "
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh

  --> Creating sles-15--server-basesystem-x86_64 Repositories <--


  --> Creating sles-15--server-application-x86_64 Repositories <--


  --> Creating sles-15--server-development_tools-x86_64 Repositories <--
```

or if you really want to loop on the indices for some reason:

```
for Add_RePos in "${!RePos[@]}"
do
  echo "
  $(tput setaf 2)--> Creating ${RePos[Add_RePos]#* } Repositories <--$(tput sgr0)
  "
done
```

You had also used `declare -p` (print) instead of `declare -a` (array) to declare your array.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the loop to do other things, a simple `printf` with an expanded array variable would do as well:

```bash
printf "\n  $(tput setaf 2)--> Creating %s Repositories <--$(tput sgr0)\n  \n" "${RePos[@]##* }"
```

```
  --> Creating sles-15--server-basesystem-x86_64 Repositories <--
  

  --> Creating sles-15--server-application-x86_64 Repositories <--
  

  --> Creating sles-15--server-development_tools-x86_64 Repositories <--
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want an assosiative array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

MntPnt=/mnt/c
SerPck=sles-15-sp3
declare -A RePos=("$MntPnt"/Module-Basesystem\  sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-basesystem-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Server-Applications\  sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-application-x86_64
                  "$MntPnt"/Module-Development-Tools\  sles-15-"$ServPck"-server-development_tools-x86_64
                 )
for Add_RePos in "${!RePos[@]}"
do
  echo "\"$Add_RePos\" Creating \"${RePos[$Add_RePos]}\" Repositories"
done
```

Output:

```
"/mnt/c/Module-Development-Tools " Creating "sles-15--server-development_tools-x86_64" Repositories
"/mnt/c/Module-Basesystem " Creating "sles-15--server-basesystem-x86_64" Repositories
"/mnt/c/Module-Server-Applications " Creating "sles-15--server-application-x86_64" Repositories
```